# Implementation of pure virtual method with/without virtual?

Tags: c++, class, methods, virtual, abstract

If I have an AbstractClass with a "virtual void Method()=0". What is the difference if a DerivedClass defines the implementation as "virtual void Method() { }" or simply "void Method() { }" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. It's just for clarity.

Any method defined as virtual in a base class, is also virtual in the classes which inherit from it, regardless whether it's declared like that or not.